# Локально работающий скрипт не находит класс на хостинге

Tags: php

Доброго всем времени суток, господа

Локально работающий скрипт создания Excel документов, на хостинге не может найти свой класс.

Буквально вчера, решение из интернета, которым пользовался давно дало сбой (уже почти пол года). Пробовал разбираться сам, и зашел в тупик. Локально - работает, нет проблем. На хостинге - ошибки.

[Решение](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/list/changesets?ProjectName=phpexcel): из него нужно взять каталог **trunk/Classes/** и в php файле написать

```
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

$phpexcel = new PHPExcel();
$page = $phpexcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$page->setCellValue("B2", "Hello");
$page->setTitle("Test");
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpexcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

у меня повторюсь - ошибки локально не выдает. Просто чистая страница, и рядом с php файлом появляется excel файл, в котором что нужно. На хостинге:

> `Fatal error: Class 'XMLWriter' not found in /home/../mysite.ru/../../excel/PHPExcel/Shared/XMLWriter.php on line 44 (в место .. мои каталоги)`

Прошу совета, может кто пользовался данным решением, знает что не так?

p.s. еще немного подлило масла в огонь то, что вчера же я и посоветовал это решение в одном из ответов, ответил, а потом думаю проверю и... 8-(

Comment: Проверьте еще раз пути. Для локального хостинга под виндой (скорее всего, Ваш вариант) без разницы регистр букв. Апач под линухом же -- чувствителен к этому.
Ну и плюс на хостинге может быть отключен XMLWriter, посмотрите в выводе функции phpinfo()

Comment: там везде enabled и active. версия 5.2.1. Можно как то указать включение XMLWriter? что с буквами предлагаете? (я этот каталог дублировал с матеники ми буквами - не помогло)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обратитесь к хостеру, ошибка же очевидна: проверить пути, если там все ок, то возможно хостер обновил пхп (раз раньше все работало) и исключил данный класс из пакета. возножно просто ошибка хостера. уточните у них обновляли ли чтото...

Comment: наверное это верный вариант, т.к. версия PHP у них новая всегда. что то на химичили значит

Answer (score 2):

> XMLWriter является расширением PHP. Оно создает XmlWriter API на основе библиотеки libxml.

Обычно по умолчанию присутствует, однако на хостинге может быть [старая версия PHP, в которую данное расширение не входит](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/xmlwriter.installation.php).

**PS.** Если не секрет, какого размера файлы генерируете, и сколько memory_limit установлен?

Comment: не секрет. вот пример который привел - не работает

    // только это
    "B2", "Hello"

memory_limit - даже не трогал

Answer (score 1):

Была подобная проблема при переезде на новый сервер:

1) Проверяем установлен ли модуль libxml:

```
php -i | grep "xml"
```

Пример результата:

```
1   /etc/php.d/xmlreader.ini,
2   /etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini,
3   xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
4   xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
5   libxml
6   mbstring.http_output_conv_mimetypes => ^(text/|applicatio...
7   Simplexml support => enabled
8   xml
9   libxml2 Version => 2.7.6
10  xmlwriter
```

Строки 5, 9 и 10, говорят что всё установлено.

2) Устанавливаем (если phpinfo свидетельствует об отсутствии, пример для CentOS):

```
yum install libxml2
```

и перезагрузить сервер:

```
/etc/apache2 restart
```

или для php-fpm:

```
/etc/php-fpm restart
```

ещё можно попробовать следующее:

```
yum install php-xmlwriter
yum install php-xml
```

Для php собранного из исходников, в последних версиях `xmlwriter` включен по умолчанию, но следует убедиться, что ключ `--disable-xmlwriter` не был включен при сборке.


**3) И наконец то с чем я столкнулся** - в файле:

```
/etc/php.d/xmlwriter.ini
```

Должно быть примерно следующее:

```
; Enable xmlwriter extension module
extension=xmlwriter.so
```

Хотя вообщем суть в том, чтобы эти строки были прописаны в нужно ***ini*** файле.